# Placing images together

Tags: positioning, subfloats

I am currently experiencing difficulties in gathering 2 png.files on a single page and look for tips.

```
\section{\textalpha-section}
\begin{center}
 Figure 3: title
 \end{center}

 \begin{figure}[p]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pic1}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pic2}
  \end{figure}
```

The problem is as follows: the section title and Figure 3: title are on 1 page and everything else is empty up to the following page where pic1 & pic2 are displayed adequately.

Thus is there a way to keep the section, Figure 3 and the pictures on the same page?

I've eventually managed to implement this task, and below is my solution (As a way around I've used 4 pictures.eps in a `2*2 array`:

```
  \section{test section}
  \begin{center}
  Figure 3: test title
   \end{center}
   \begin{figure}[h]
   \begin{center}$
    \begin{array}{ll}
    \includegraphics [scale=0.49]{fig1.eps}&
    \includegraphics [scale=0.4]{fig2.eps}
    \end{array}$\\
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}$
     \begin{array}{rr}
            \includegraphics [scale=0.5]{fig3.eps}&
            \includegraphics [scale=0.5]{fig4.eps}
            \end{array}$
            \end{center}

      \end{figure}
```

Hoping it will help others.

Best,

Comment: have you tried `scale=0.5` or less?

Comment: i did it without significant improvement, unfortunately.

Comment: You should specify a height or width, not a scale factor.

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you can use `subfigure` environnement you have to use `\usepackage{subcaption}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 %\graphicspath{{C:/local/pic/} }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
   \section{test}

\begin{figure*}
\caption{Wombat}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic2}
 \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: it's ending up with  `LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.` do you know the reason?

Comment: @owner see my edit `;-)` just use `\usepackage{subfigure}`

Comment: `Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }.` weird there is no extra `}` anywhere. I am keep checking the origin. Cheers

Comment: @owner add a complete MWE with the documentclass and every package and I help you

Comment: @ok. i've edited the post and hope it helps. cheers

Comment: @owner I propose you another solution

Comment: ok. let me know

Comment: `subfigure` is deprecated. Use `subcaption` instead.

Comment: @HarishKumar: , compilation fails as system looks for a potential missing  `}`  but there are none. `! Paragraph ended before \filename@path was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.57 \includegraphics
                     [scale=0.8]{fig1}
I suspect you've forgotten a }, causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. <argument> ...\@finalstrut \strutbox \fi }{}\par }`. Really weird as test contains very few lines, so it's impossible to miss  `}`

Comment: The answer still recommends` subfigure` but the example uses `subcaption`. Shouldn't the caption of the figure be inside the figure environment?